# R check if at least 20% of a vector has a particular value

Tags: r, if-statement, percentage

Say I have a vector of x length. I want to check if at least 20% of the elements of this vector have a value below 0.00001. How would I do that?

So far I know that I can figure out how to get 20% of the vector, which should just be `length(vector)/5`.

I am not sure how to do the rest. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
percentage<-(length(which(x<.000001))/length(x))*100
if(percentage<20) { .....}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
x <- 1:100
mean(x < 10) >= 0.2    # replace 10 with 0.00001 or whatever you need
#[1] FALSE
```

This uses the fact that you can perform mathematical operations, like taking the mean, of logical vectors.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(sum(which(vector < 0.00001) == T) >= length(vector)/5) {
   --- check ---
}
```